# Avoid multiple Instances in workflow Ax2009

Tags: workflow, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, enterprise-portal

Whenever the user submits a workflow request from **Enterprise portal** clicking more than once, multiple instances are generated. Kindly suggest a way to avoid as it is misleading.

[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/solutions/2008/07/30/using-microsoft-dynamics-ax-2009-workflow-controls-in-ep/)

In the event `this.WorkflowActionBar.EvaluatingCanSubmitToWorkflow` you could via the EP's Business Connector session call a static method in X++ to check whether a workflow for your current process / document / whatever already exists and avoid submitting it again. How you determine that of course depends on your environment / process etc.